# SQL nested select where condition is met or if row not in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

The title is not clear as I don't know how to express the problem in one sentence.

I have a table named companies, looks like this:

| Symbol (PK) | Exchange (PK) |
| --- | --- |
| TSLA | NASDAQ |
| AMZN | NASDAQ |
| MCSFT | NASDAQ |

And then I have a table where I record the last crawl operations I made.
The idea is having a script that can restart crawling everyday without recrawling companies that have been done.

Crawl_Settings

| Symbol (PK/FK on companies) | Exchange(PK/FK) | Last crawl date | Number of articles crawled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TSLA | NASDAQ | 19/11/2021 | 20 |
| AMZN | NASDAQ | 12/11/2021 | 20 |

I thought about making a query that would get me all the companies that have a last crawl date that is not today.

```
Select * from companies where symbol,exchange in (
  select symbol,exchange from crawl_settings where date != today
)
```

I think that this query will work, but won't get me the  companies that have never been crawled.
Expected result:

| Symbol (PK) | Exchange (PK) |
| --- | --- |
| AMZN | NASDAQ |
| MCSFT | NASDAQ |

explanation: AMZN has an old crawl date, MCSFT has never been crawled.

Actual result:

| Symbol (PK) | Exchange (PK) |
| --- | --- |
| AMZN | NASDAQ |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impaler's solution is objectively better, because NOT IN has some finicky behavior. But just putting it out there that you were very close to being on the right track.

Just tweak where your inequality is.

```
Select * from companies where symbol,exchange not in (
  select symbol,exchange from crawl_settings where date = today
)
```

Comment: Yes, this is simple, easier to read and will work well in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an anti-join to get the rows you want. For example:

```
select c.*
from companies c
left join crawl_settings s on s.symbol = c.symbol 
                          and s.exchange = c.exchange
                          and s.date = today
where s.symbol is null
```

Comment: With this I will only get the rows where the symbol is null right? I'll still have to run my query above to get the rows that have a symbol AND date != today. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: This query also returns the symbols that don't have a date of today.

Comment: Tried this on my db, seems that the correct query for my case is this:
select c.*, s.date
from companies c
left join crawl_settings s on s.symbol = c.symbol 
                          and s.exchange = c.exchange
                          and s.date < '2021-11-19'

as I get both the companies that have been crawled at an old date AND the one that have not been crawled.
Your request deletes the companies that have a date. Since their s.symbol is not null

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to check crawler run for symbol and add a condition for check crawler not run in today then combine with `OR`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5f619291f967a9de9d9a110c16e58188)

```sql
select 
  c.symbol,
  c.exchange
from 
  companies c
  left join crawl_settings cs on c.symbol = cs.symbol and c.exchange = cs.exchange
where
  cs.last_crawl_date isnull
  or cs.last_crawl_date != current_date
```

Comment: I went with something like this, I just deleted the crawl_date isnull since that will stay as it is a left join. Only condition in the where is the date.